# angularJs - `$window.location.href` - throws an error in firefox alone

Tags: angularjs, firefox

In my angular application, I am re-directing the user by conditinal. all are works fine other than `firefox` browser.

`firefox` browser considers this `$window.location.href` - as a server side request and my app `trigger` the error, because of unknown call. `chrome,ie` works fine.

here is my code :

```
fn.redirectToLogin = function() {

        var site = fn.env.auth;
        var clientId = fn.env.oauth.client_id;
        var redirectUri = fn.env.oauth.redirect_uri;
        var authorizePath = String( "authorization.oauth2?response_type=token&client_id=" );
        var state = fn.env.state;


        var URL = encodeURI(site + authorizePath + clientId + '&redirect_uri=&scope=&state=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(state)));
        $window.location.href = URL;//requesting to server!! throws error

        console.log( 'fn.env.state::', fn.env.state );

    }

    if( !$rootScope.isUserLoggedIn && fn.env.state !== undefined ) {

        console.log('going to call auto login!');
        fn.redirectToLogin();

    }
```

Comment: Could you add what kind of error is thrown on this line `$window.location.href = URL;//requesting to server!! throws error` ?

Comment: Actually, my app has multiple errors on specific request. in case of above issue, i am getting default error as "something wrong" - then my app works properly. this only in firefox

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to change URL in Angular is `$location.url(URL)`. Inject `$location` in your controller and use it instead of directly setting value. [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) you can read more about it.

Comment: Sure, let me try it out.

Comment: actually, this is not works for me. it consider as  a internal page change. but my case is i am redirecting to external website for `SSO` - login purpose.